# How do I make a list of upcoming events in views with the date module?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I'm on D7. I have the date module installed and I want to make a views block of upcoming events. I have a content type "event" and it has a date field. The list needs to only show events that have a date past the current one (there is no real point in showing events that have already happened :) ). I am having no luck finding anything on how to do this and I feel like this functionality is a common need. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Here is a test view I have created to show what I have tried. :)

Using "Date:Date" filter criterion

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'test';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'test';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'test';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '5';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['id'] = 'field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['table'] = 'field_data_field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['field'] = 'field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['settings'] = 
array(
  'format_type' => 'long',
  'fromto' => 'both',
  'multiple_number' => '',
  'multiple_from' => '',
  'multiple_to' => '',
);
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = 
array(
  'event' => 'event',
    );
/* Filter criterion: Date: Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['id'] =         'date_filter';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['field'] = 'date_filter';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['operator'] = '>=';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['granularity'] = 'second';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['default_date'] = 'now';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['date_fields'] =   
array(
  'field_data_field_date.field_date_value' => 'field_data_field_date.field_date_value',
);

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['hide_admin_links'] = FALSE;
```

Using "Content:Date" filter criterion

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'test';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'test';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'test';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '5';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['id'] = 'field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['table'] = 'field_data_field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['field'] = 'field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_date']['settings'] = 
array(
  'format_type' => 'long',
  'fromto' => 'both',
  'multiple_number' => '',
  'multiple_from' => '',
  'multiple_to' => '',
);
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = 
array(
  'event' => 'event',
    );
/* Filter criterion: Content: Date (field_date) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value']['id'] = 'field_date_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_date';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value']['field'] = 'field_date_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value']['operator'] = '>=';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value']['granularity'] = 'hour';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_date_value']['default_date'] = 'now';

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['hide_admin_links'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is create a new view that shows content of type 'event'... set that on the first page of creating your view. Make sure you check the 'block' option at the bottom - it's up to you whether you also want to create a page display or not, that's checked by default.  Also, before moving onto the second page, make sure that your view is a list of 'fields' rather than 'teasers'.

On the next page, in order to limit to upcoming events, make sure you create a new filter on your view based on the event's date.  To limit it to current and future events, you should enter a **relative**, as opposed to, a hard-coded date.  Here's how I would set up that filter:

[image]

That should be it.  Add whichever fields you want and limit to as many listings as you want!

Let us know if this works!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Every time I try this, it ends up not showing any of the "events". I have tried filtering by the "Content:Date" field, as well as the "Date:Date" field. Ill export the test view I have created above. :)

Comment: It should be Content:<name of your date field>.... as long as it's a view of content filtered by the type event.  Are you sure you actually have events that appear in the future (with the date field filled out and everything)?  Do events appear before you select the filter (this would help us figure out if its the filter that's problematic)?

Comment: The events do show when there is no filter, I have test events submitted that have dates ranging from 4 days ago to a month from now.